# Western Digital 1TB SATAII 64MB freezes or slows down my PC

Tags: windows, hard-drive, storage

My new PC frequently freezes every few seconds, or goes slow. Performance is under the typical speed.  I'm sure this is not related to an infection after writing on Tom's Hardware Italy.  Some kind gentleman confirmed that the problem is connected to my HD.

The PC has a Western Digital 1TB SATAII 64MB divided in two partitions:

- C:\ 238 GB with the OS (Windows XP Professional Version 2002 service pack 3) and some basic applications (Office, browser, Photoshop, games, etc.)
- D:\ (693 GB) to archive data like movies, photos, documents, etc.

In addition to that I have a second HD Maxtor 6Y080M0 (G:/ 80 GB) from an old PC of mine with data similar to the D:/ drive.  Tom's Hardware Forum told me that Green Hard Drives like the Western Digital are built for storage and not for running the OS.

Do I need to have a new, smaller HD? Is there an ideal right size that should used for an OS startup drive?

If the new smaller HDD is bigger than 500 GB will I have to partition it?
If so, what size should I have for the 2 partitions?

**My system:**

- AMD Phenom II X4 955 Black Box 125W
- Asus M4A785TD-M EVO
- Radeon HD5770 1GB GDDR5 Asus
- CoolerMaster GX 650W
- G.Skill 2x2GB PC3-12800 1600Mhz-787 4GBECO
- Western Digital 1TB SATAII 64MB
- CoolerMaster cm690 II Advanced Tower Black
- 3 x Enermax Everest 120mm Blue Led

Comment: Is this a green drive?

Comment: Is your SATA controller set to IDE, AHCI, or RAID mode in your BIOS?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the [WD Align utility](http://wdc.com/en/products/advancedformat/) if you're going to use this drive with Windows XP and more than one volume/partition. If you haven't done this yet, please do so and see if it doesn't cure the problem.

Comment: Deleting embarrasing incorrect information... I thought it would delete all your data, but re-reading the page, it probably won't.  You should definitely back up your data just in case.

Comment: Aligning only helps with AF drives, and i somehow doubt that a 1tb drive would be AF